# Passing type as a parameter

Tags: c#, .net-core, types, method-parameters

I have a method which takes an object of a certain inherited type and searches for it in the internal data structure...

```
public (bool,Point) GetItemPosition(IMyBaseType type)
{
    ...
}
```

So the use of the above method would be something like this:

```
var (isFound, location) = myDataContainer.GetItemPosition(myDataItem);
```

In the data structure class, I want to make use of the search method. However, I don't want to have to create an instance of the desired data item (because that has an overhead) - I just want to pass the class type as a value. Currently, I am creating a data item instance...

```
public bool AddTarget()
{
    var (hasTarget, location) = GetItemPosition(new SomeDataItem().GetType() as IMyBaseType, 0, 0);
    ...
}
```

How can I pass the class type itself?

Comment: Do you mean that `GetItemPosition` will search for anything that has the passed-in type, rather than anything that is `Equals` to the passed-in object? Is the passed in type always known at compile time?

Comment: Yes and yes. I wish to search for the passed in type but ensure that it is of a certain base class.

Comment: I realise my definition of the `GetItemPosition` is not good here. The first parameter needs changing to something which accepts a type and not an instance - but that is my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use generics:

```
public (bool,Point) GetItemPosition<T>() where T: IMyBaseType
{
    ...
}
```

In the method, you would refer to the passed in type as `T`. You can check, for example, if an `object obj` is of type `T` with `is`:

```
if (obj is T) { ... }
```

The caller would look like:

```
GetItemPosition<SomeDataItem>()
```